# Does $\mathcal{P}\neq\mathcal{NP}$ imply $\mathcal{NP}\neq\mathcal{NP}^{\mathcal{NP}}$?

Tags: complexity-theory

I cannot see whether the implication in my question title holds. To me, it sounds reasonable to assume that, but I cannot find any source stating that this is true, false, or unknown at the moment.

So, **does $\mathcal{P}\neq\mathcal{NP}$ imply $\mathcal{NP}\neq\mathcal{NP}^{\mathcal{NP}}$**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, *this implication is not known to be true*, however it is believed that those are all separate classes.  (Unfortunately, I don't have any references to back up my claim now, but I still post this as an answer to point out the following.)

You are asking whether $\text{P} \neq \text{NP}$ implies that *the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) $(\text{PH})$ does not collapse to its first level*.

The class $\text{NP}^\text{NP}$ is also known as $\Sigma_2^P$ which is one of the classes on the *second level* of the polynomial hierarchy.